# Cannot get date-fns to work in material-ui/react. Keep getting can't find errors

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, date-fns

I had started working w/React a month ago.  Downloaded a bunch of libraries some of which were useful.  But when I tried to get date-io/date-fns to work I got stuck.  I was getting strange errors of not being able to find 'Button in @material-ui', so I went to look in my folder structure and found THREE COPIES of package.json in my project!!  I had been installing packages into the default folder when you open a command window in vscode.  Don't know who they ended up all over the place.

Anway, I decided to start a new project from scratch in vscode and copy all my source folders over, then reinstall all the packages I was using.  Here's what I did:

- created a new vscode .net core project/react js (no redux)
- copied my source folder from my old project folder to the new one. replacing all files/folders in the new project.
- opened up a powershell cmd window.  Entered the following commands:

  ```
  yarn upgrade react
  yarn add react-router
  yarn add-react-router-dom
  yarn add formik
  yarn add yup
  yarn add @material-io/core
  yarn add @material-io/icons
  yarn add @material-io/pickers
  yarn add @date-io
  yarn add @date-io/date-fns
  yarn add yup
  ```

Okay, so then I compiled the app and ran it.  I STILL get a date-fn error, but a different one now:

Module not found: Can't resolve 'date-fns/_lib/format/longFormatters' in 'C:\projects\DoxaProject\DoxaUI\DoxaUI\node_modules@date-io\date-fns\build'

My package.json file has the latest dependencies, INCLUDING date-io/date-fns.

Why am I getting this error?  I've now spend a day trying to just get ONE date field working.  If anyone can help I'd truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was to explicitly add `date-fns` to my project.

```
yarn add date-fns
```

Hope that solves your frustrating problem.

Comment: Ok. So I did what you said.  I did

yarn add date-fns

and reran the app.  Now I receive a different error:

"RangeError: Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `n`

(anonymous function)
C:/projects/DoxaProject/DoxaUI/DoxaUI/node_modules/date-fns/esm/format/index.js:421"

Why is this so difficult?  I haven't had this issue w/any other library, but date-fns is a disaster so far.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found the problem.  It turns out that using the above while the right *idea* doesn't work, because there's a bug in date-fns 2.x when mixed w/material-ui pickers that I had above.

The solution is to remove the latest version of date-fns and replace it with a 1.x version:


     npm i @date-io/date-fns@1.x date-fns


This fixed that issue.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: true! I found myself fighting with the same issue... quite frustrating

Answer (score 2):

the material-ui/pickers document:

Important: For material-ui-pickers v3 use v1.x version of @date-io adapters.

yarn add @date-io/dayjs@1.x

===========================
you should user 1.x